# Query to find rowcount of a table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mongodb, oracle11g, database

I am trying to find the query to find the row and byte count of a table from each backend database:

I) MySQL
II) Oracle DB
III) SQL Server
IV) Mongo DB
V) Teradata

Comment: what's your question and what you have got ?

Comment: Have the right direction for MySQL, oracl and sql server right now. Looking for the right query in MySQL, sql server, mongodb and Teradata. I am looking for a query that can obtain these information from table stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MySQL**

```
Row count of single table

select count(*) from table_name;

Row Count of all tables

SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database schema name';

Size
SELECT table_schema as `Database`, 
     table_name AS `Table`, 
     round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

Result for size would be like this

```
Database Table              Size in MB
sakai    sakai_realm_rl_fn  22.39
sonar    file_sources       8.56
sakai    sakai_site_tool    4.55
sakai    sakai_event        4.03
sonar    issues             3.75
sakai    sakai_site_page    3.03
sonar    project_measures   2.03
```

**MongoDB**
In mongoDB we don't have rows and columns, but everything is documents, so we can find the number of documents in a collection and the size of it.

```
db.collection.stats() // example db.stackoverflow.stats(), where stackoverflow is my collection name
```

The result would be similar to this

```
{
        "ns" : "test.stackoverflow",
```

> ```
>       "count" : 2,
> ```

```
        "size" : 224,
        "avgObjSize" : 112,
        "numExtents" : 1,
```

> ```
>       "storageSize" : 8192,
> ```

```
        "lastExtentSize" : 8192,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "paddingFactorNote" : "paddingFactor is unused and unmaintained in 3.0. It remains hard coded to 1.0 for compatibility only.",
        "userFlags" : 1,
        "capped" : false,
        "nindexes" : 1,
        "totalIndexSize" : 8176,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 8176
        },
        "ok" : 1
}


db.stats(); // Will help us in finding the total documents in the database

Executing it in mongo shell, will a give a result like this

{
        "db" : "test",
        "collections" : 9,
        "objects" : 1000063,
        "avgObjSize" : 112.00058396321032,
        "dataSize" : 112007640,
        "storageSize" : 175837184,
        "numExtents" : 20,
        "indexes" : 12,
        "indexSize" : 169938160,
        "fileSize" : 2080374784,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 70,
                "totalSize" : 760217600
        },
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 22
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Here objects is the number of documents across collections

More info - http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats

**Oracle**

```
Row count of single table
select count(*) from table_name

Total Size
select * from dba_data_files;

select round((sum(bytes)/1048576/1024),2) from v$datafile;

To execute these queries you need to login as system user with all priveleges
```

Comment: Perfect ! How can I pick storage size and count from the mongodb stats?

Comment: `db.stats()`, will help us in finding the total documents across collections in the db - Updated the same in the answer section

Answer (score 1):

The answer to #1 is `show table status` or `select table_name, table_rows from information_schema.tables`

Comment: From the entire list of information it provides, how do I specifically retrieve the row count alone ?

Comment: Thanks. Check if this is right :  select table_name, table_Rows, data_length from information_Schema.tables where table_name='XXX';